# SparkContext.clean java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: apache-spark

This weird exception is terminating my spark task, any ideas?

I am "submitting" a lot of smaller tasks to spark context via sc.parallelize(... seq of 256 items ...) . (don't ask me why but this is what I need).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:679)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:415)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyStream(Utils.scala:347)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getInnerClasses(ClosureCleaner.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.flatMap(RDD.scala:295)
at com.stratified.pdfingestion.CermineJob$.extractPdfText(CermineJob.scala:53)
at com.stratified.pdfingestion.CermineJob$.execute(CermineJob.scala:41)
at com.stratified.pdfingestion.CermineJob$$anonfun$main$1.apply(CermineJob.scala:31)
at com.stratified.pdfingestion.CermineJob$$anonfun$main$1.apply(CermineJob.scala:29)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at com.stratified.pdfingestion.CermineJob$.main(CermineJob.scala:29)
at com.stratified.pdfingestion.CermineJob.main(CermineJob.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have this problem in another context, my guess so far is that the zip-Archive is created with a newer specification than the library is able to speak.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember the issue or if I did find a solution

Comment: Okay, I am trying to find an answer to this, just in case this comes up or anyone stumbles over this post with the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480085/unpacking-zip-files-in-java-that-cause-a-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid

Comment: any updates? I seem to get this in my spark streaming application, not sure were its coming from...

Answer (score 9):

Not sure this is the same problem that your running into as I am, but I found that if I do a spark summit and while the job is running and I start modifying that same jar (ie scp a new build to cluster) I get this error.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:679)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:415)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply$mcJ$sp(Utils.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply(Utils.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply(Utils.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1250)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyStream(Utils.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getInnerClosureClasses(ClosureCleaner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.map(DataFrame.scala:1449)
    at com.xxxxxx.spark.streaming.driver.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$$anonfun$main$2.apply(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.scala:74)
    at com.xxxxxx.spark.streaming.driver.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$$anonfun$main$2.apply(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is a bit off topic but the other error I get some time when I do the same thing is :

```
java.io.IOException: Class not found
   at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:40)
   at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getInnerClosureClasses(ClosureCleaner.scala:81)
   at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:187)
   at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(RDD.scala:333)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(RDD.scala:332)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.flatMap(RDD.scala:332)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FlatMappedDStream$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(FlatMappedDStream.scala:35)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FlatMappedDStream$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(FlatMappedDStream.scala:35)
   at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FlatMappedDStream.compute(FlatMappedDStream.scala:35)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
   at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
   at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FilteredDStream.compute(FilteredDStream.scala:35)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
   at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
   at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:47)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:115)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
   at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:248)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:246)
   at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:246)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:181)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:86)
   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Comment: That would explain it for my case. Exactly the same problem and I really did submit a new jar for local execution on a "big" machine. Thanks for this hint!

Comment: It explain also in my case. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got same issues, and the problem is `scp` pipe didn't copied entire jar or connection was closed in the copying time.

That means the runnable `jar` is not copied properly.

I ran again scp to copy `jar` file and after seeing completion `100%` than i again ran `spark-submit` job using that `jar`, successfully ran job :)